# I am making a battleship game in Python and i want to add more ships

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the original code that only has one ship:

```
#Battleships
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(8):
    board.append(["O "] * 8)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleship!\n\n")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

for turn in range(5):
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print ("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        if turn==5:
            print ("Game Over")

        elif (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 7) or (guess_col < 0 or  guess_col > 7):
             print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X "):
             print ("You guessed that one already.")
        else:
             print ("You missed my battleship!")
             board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X "
        print ("Turn:",turn+1)
        print_board(board)
```

Then I tried to add more ships but it did not work:

```
#Battleships
from random import randint
board = []

for x in range(8):
    board.append(["O "] * 8)


def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleship!\n\n")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
import random
ships = [['row',random_row,'col',random_col]]
for i in range(9):
    ships.append(['row',random_row,'col',random_col])
random.choice(ships)() #i am lost




def main():

    for turn in range(64):
        guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))

        if guess_row == random_row in ships and guess_col == random_col in ships:
            print ("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
            continue
        else:
            if turn==65:
                print ("Game Over")
                break

            elif (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 7) or (guess_col < 0 or  guess_col > 7):
                print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X "):
                print ("You guessed that one already.")
            else:
                print ("You missed my battleship!")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X "
            print ("Turn:",turn+1)
            print_board(board)

main()
```

Comment: Please make sure that your code is formatted properly, it will make it much easier for people to understand it, thanks. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - when you say, "Doesn't work", that doesn't clearly describe the problem. If you get an error, please post the exact traceback that you're getting. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: Shouldn't you check for collisions among your (more than one ships), and extending ships outside of the board bounderies?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make a `Ship` class, and then make a `list` of `Ship`s. Something like this.

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, col, row):
        self.col = col
        self.row = row
# Say you want 5 ships
NUMBER_OF_SHIPS = 5
ships = []
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_SHIPS):
    # random_row, random_col, and board are just like you had them
    ships.append(Ship(random_col(board), random_row(board)))

# After you get the guesses...

for i in ships:
    if guess_row == i.row and guess_col == i.col:
        # Player wins... 
        break
    finally: 
        # Player loses
```

Answer (score 0):

im making an rpg game with multiple heros, think of the multiple heros like you're multiple ships

```
class warrior(object):
    name = "warrior"
    health = 150
    strength = 5
    armor = 10
    coins = 0

class rouge(object):
    name = "rouge"
    health = 75
    strength = 15
    armor = 2
    coins = 0

#enemy classes
class fairy(object):
    name = "fairy"
    health = 10
    strength = 10
    coins = random.randint(1,50)

class troll(object):
    name = "troll"
    health = 20
    strength = 25
    coins = random.randint(25,100)
```

you make a class and if the class is called then it takes the variables or whatever. so you should make classes for ships.